# tar archive and checksum empty

Tags: centos, backup, tar, hashsum

On a centos 7 I'm trying to arhive and do a checksum over a directory but at the end the files are empty.

```
localpath=/backup
name=$(date '+%Y-%m-%d')
tar cvzf $localpath/BackUp$name.tgz $localpath/BackUp* | md5sum $localpath/BackUp$name.tgz > $localpath/checksum$name
```

Can you please advise on what I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pipe, `|`, is used for sending the output of the command on the left-hand side to the input of the command on the right-hand side.  The commands on the left and right-hand side are started concurrently, and it is only the writing and reading from the left to the right that synchronises the two parts of the pipeline.

In this case, the `tar` command is not outputting anything that `md5sum` should read, and `md5sum` is given a filename to process, so it wouldn't read its standard input stream anyway.

What you probably want to do is to *not* use a pipe and instead invoke `md5sum` once the `tar` command has created your archive.

```bash
tar -vz -c -f "$localpath/BackUp$name.tgz" some files
md5sum "$localpath/BackUp$name.tgz" >"$localpath/BackUp$name.md5"
```